# Error Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…) en angular

Tags: array, angular, push

Estoy haciendo un formulario dinamico en angular, quiero crear un nuevo "formcontrolname" en donde pusheo un array nuevo y me sale un error.
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Siroco-Mt, al como dice el error no se puede leer la propiedad _push_ de un _undefined_ . Buscando desde la primera linea en la que asignas un valor a List, es posible que List2[0] obviamente sea el valor indefinido, pero no tenemos conocimiento de los valores anteriores a eso. Por favor no pegues imágenes, procura subir el código y todo lo que respecta al contexto del mismo. si nos das el código incompleto es mas complicado el poder ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

Podrías dejar tu código de la siguiente manera:

```
 let nameParam = [];
 for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++){
  if(typeof List[name[i]] === 'boolean'){
    this.nameParam.push(this.formFields)
  }
}
```

Si declaras **nameParam** dentro del **for**, por cada iteración que haga el valor se estará restableciendo y prácticamente el **push** que haces no tiene ningún efecto.